# What makes a good form?

Tags: forms

I've recently been given the challenge to create a preferably 'fun and engaging'-form, consisting of about 40-50 fields. The form consists of four parts, Employee-contact-info, Employment-description, Competency, and Experience.

I suspect the 'fun and engaging'-bit can be dropped, but how can I make the form as painless as possible to fill in?

I have no prior experience with designing for good user experience, so any thoughts or resources on how to tackle this kind of challenge is appreciated.

I've already found [this](http://formulate.com.au/articles/what-makes-a-good-form/) describing some methods to make forms as good as possible.

Comment: They key to a good form is to not have 40-50 fields. ;) Is there anyway to segregate the form into 'required right now' vs. 'this stuff can be entered later'?

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/27/useful-ideas-and-guidelines-for-good-web-form-design/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A good place to start is Luke Wroblewski and his various writings on form design

eg
http://www.lukew.com/presos/preso.asp?22

But to add:
From my experience building hundreds of forms, I can recommend the following:

1. Minimise the number of fields in the system. This might require a
   bit of to and fro between you and the business analyst + a little
   bit extra user research but you'll be amazed at how many superfluous
   fields there might be.
2. Clear path to completion: arrange fields and field descriptions in a
   way that the eye is led down the screen to the call to action
   buttons.
3. If there are compulsory fields mark them clearly.
4. Validate fields as the user types *not* after submit; offer in-line
   instructions
5. If you have a stack of fields, either tab them into discrete
   sections (like you indicate) or walk the user through a sequence of
   pages to final completion. edit: tabs won't work for sequential
   information or when there is compulsory information in each tab. It
   is a good approach, I have found, for containing different types of
   content in a system that the user updates or uses over a period of
   time.
6. Progressive disclosure. I allude to this is in 5). This is a way of
   avoiding cognitive burden or information overload. Put simply,
   present information in a series of simple steps instead of one big
   whole.
7. Break up longer forms into visually distinct regions. This allows
   you to group slightly different field sets together and will help
   the user build a mental model of the system, it is also a way of
   giving the impression that the system is less burdensome than it
   really is (again, this could be argued to be a type of progressive
   disclosure).

Comment: +1 for the list of idea = very good. But -1 for tabbed forms. If the whole set of data needs to be filled in, then make it clear exactly how much data needs to be completed. Tabbed forms - and even progressive reveal forms - suggest that there might be a lot more to enter that there is. IMO

Comment: a caveat to tabs that I should have posted: never use in systems that are intended for single submission.

Comment: Its a hot topic for me... http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/the-use-of-tabs

Comment: aye, me too. I've edited my answer...

Comment: You get your +1 then!!

Comment: 4. Note that you need to validate on the server too -- never trust the client. Also, if you validate and destroy something I've typed in a later form field because of a validation error, then I'll be contacting a few mad ax murderer friends of mine to take care of things :)

Comment: yes, persistence of form field data after error on submit

Comment: Meetup.com makes good use of modular tabs under [account settings](http://www.meetup.com/help/How-do-I-manage-my-Account-information/). They split "account settings" into the tabs of "general", "email settings", "payments made", "connected apps".

Answer (score 7):

A long form needs to reduce the amount of noise as much as possible so as not to intimidate the user.

There are many many ways to present a long form and it's a combination of a huge number of little details that makes the overall effect better for the user. For example, the Google Mail Create Account form for GMail is just a disaster area: bad alignment, inconsistent, wordy, dull and unfriendly looking - and yet Google Blogger Create Account form is miles better in most respects (but still not perfect).

[image]

[image]

[Luke Wroblewski](http://www.lukew.com/) has many many good tips and best practices of web form design and lists them in summarised sections at the end of each chapter in his excellent book [Web Form Design](http://www.lukew.com/resources/web_form_design.asp) - but he also has a PDF online resource of [best practices for Web Form Design](http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/WebForms_LukeW_02132008.pdf) which is also well worth reading thoroughly. Although the book has quite a few more, I quote the PDF's bullet point best practices below for quick reference, but please do see the original PDF for full details.

> - Take the time to evaluate every  question you ask
> - Ensure your forms speak with  one voice
> - Strive for succinctness
> - If a form naturally breaks down  into a few short topics, use a 
>     single Web page
> - When a form contains a large  number of questions that are  only
>     related by a few topics, try  multiple Web pages
> - When a form contains a large  number of questions related to  a
>     single topic, one long Web  page
> - Use relevant content  groupings to organize  forms
> - Use the minimum  amount of visual  elements necessary to 
>     communicate useful  relationships
> - Titles of forms should  match people’s goals
> - Illuminate a clear path  to completion
> - Use progress indicators  to communicate scope,  status, and position
> - Use more general  progress indicators for  forms with variable 
>     sequences
> - Remember to account  for tabbing behavior
> - Use the tabindex  attribute to control  tabbing (not at expense  of
>     ordering)
> - Consider tabbing  expectations when  laying out forms
> - For reduced  completion times &  familiar data input: top  aligned
> - When vertical screen  space is a constraint:  right aligned
> - For unfamiliar, or  advanced data entry:  left aligned
> - When possible, use  field length as an  affordance
> - Otherwise consider a  consistent length that  provides enough room 
>     for inputs
> - Try to avoid optional  fields
> - If most fields are  required: indicate  optional fields
> - If most fields are  optional: indicate  required fields
> - Text is best, but * often  works for required  fields
> - Associate indicators  with labels
> - When there’s more  than one way to format  an answer correctly,  use
>     a flexible input
> - Ensure flexible inputs  don’t make providing  easy answers harder
> - Avoid secondary actions if  possible
> - Otherwise, ensure a clear  visual distinction between  primary &
>     secondary actions
> - Align primary actions with  input fields for a clear path  to
>     completion
> - Provide indication of  tasks in progress
> - Disable “submit”  button after user clicks  it to avoid duplicate 
>     submissions
> - Minimize the amount of  help & tips required to  fill out a form
> - Help visible and  adjacent to a data  request is most useful
> - When lots of unfamiliar  data is being  requested, consider  using a
>     dynamic help  system
> - Clearly communicate  an error has occurred:  top placement, visual 
>     contrast
> - Provide actionable  remedies to correct  errors
> - Associate responsible  fields with primary  error message
> - “Double” the visual  language where errors  have occurred
> - Clearly communicate a  data submission has  been successful
> - Provide feedback in  context of data  submitted
> - Use inline validation for  inputs that have  potentially high error 
>     rates
> - Use suggested inputs  to disambiguate
> - Communicate limits
> - Look for opportunities  to remove unnecessary  inputs
> - Do not complicate  questions for the sake  of removing inputs
> - Default selections are  likely to stay, ensure  they align with
>     goals
> - Personal defaults allow  return users to  complete forms faster
> - Map additional inputs  to prioritized user  needs
> - Most effective when  user-initiated
> - Avoid excessive page  jumping
> - Provide ways out
> - Maintain a consistent  approach
> - If lots of dependent inputs, use  page-level
> - Vertical & horizontal tabs  perform well but have mutual 
>     exclusivity issues
> - Long list of initial inputs, few  dependent inputs for each, use 
>     drop-down menu
> - Short list of initial options &  few dependents, exposed inline
> - Maintain clear relationship  between initial selection  options
> - Clearly associate additional  inputs with their trigger
> - Avoid “jumping” that  disassociates initial selection  options
> - Try to avoid sign-up  forms
> - Allow people to  engage
> - If you auto-generate  accounts, ensure there  is clear way to access
>     it
> - Do not simply  distribute the various  input fields in a sign-up 
>     form across multiple  pages

Answer (score 2):

Some general thoughts:

1. Such a long form should never, ever, lose data user put into it. It mean autosave all way through every page, even before he click “next”.
2. Give your users sense of progress (“You already completed 60% of the test. 15 more minutes to go!”). Reward them somehow when they complete a big stage (tell a joke, for example).
3. Give them ability to come back and correct their answers at any time. Even after completion you could give them 15-minutes window to fix what they want to fix.
4. Ask only if you really, really, really cannot live without this data. Every additional field means N% less users will finish your survey.
5. Provide examples of what you expect the user to write (avoid general “comment” fields, it will be confusing and results for you will be a mess, explain what you expect).
6. To make it fun, you could add some funny facts at margins, maybe statistical data (“60% select yes”, “women usually answer no this question”, etc) or historical fact corresponding to question.

Answer (score 2):

"'fun and engaging'-form, consisting of about 40-50 fields" - that is a problem to start with. I doubt that it can be done.

Firstly, split it up. Divide it into sections, but make it clear how much there is of it.

Secondly, look at the information you are collecting, and see if you can reduce the number of fields to enter - maybe making some optional.

Thirdly, consider what you can do to keep the users attention. As Nikita suggested, interesting facts, or some clear indication of how far through, or comments about how sorry you are that there are so many fields, but just a few more.

Fourthly, save everything, and allow people to come back to it and finish the job. Remember that most people DO NOT want to fill out this form. SO you have to make it as simple as possible for them.

Answer (score 2):

Making a web-form fun is going to be hard. I know Luke Wroblewski has already been mentioned, but I'd especially suggest checking out the article on [Mad-Lib style forms](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1007). That's about as close to fun as you are likely to get with a form.

Comment: wow dude, 25-40% increase from trail study....sounds real promising +1

Answer (score 1):

If you're using multiple webpages - let the user look through them first - without forcing them to complete the first page before you will show them the second page.

Otherwise users will fill the first page with garbage data - so that they can get to see the second page.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [recent blog bost](http://uxmovement.com/forms/9-things-designers-can-learn-from-targets-checkout-form/) (September 13, 2011) about the redesign of the Target checkout form that highlighted a lot of interesting things they're doing. Several good takeaways there to get you going.